# How can a data processor pass the latest caching time to the FLUIDTEMPLATE?

Tags: caching, typo3, fluid, data-processing

The results from a data processor in the fluid template are cached.

My data processor determines a list of images and a maximum time until which the list can be cached. How do I forward this information about the maximum caching time to the FLUIDTEMPLATE so that the FLUIDTEMPLATE automatically reduces or adjusts the caching time if necessary?

(My use case:
I want to use different images as wallpaper for a web page depending on the time of day.)

Is there a method, which I can call?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done that, and I fear it is more complicated than one would expect. The following two documentation entries might be helpful:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/12.4/en-us/Functions/Cache.html#cache
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Index.html

I'd consider testing `stdWrap.cache` within the TypoScript or DataProcessor. The `ContentObjectRenderer` received by the Processor is the implementation of TypoScript. The instance provides the methods like `stdWrap` which can be called with an PHP array containing the configuration.

I've never used the stdWrap.cache, but it should work accordingly to the docs.